# JQuery - iframe woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Solved: I'm an idiot. - For reference this updates iframes in a very simple manner.

http://jsfiddle.net/piezack/bDQH5/8/

Edit: Why does jsFiddle think the bbc news website doesn't exist?

Comment: What problem do you have with an array?

Comment: +1 for a problem I've never seen before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you forgot to select `jQuery` in the dropdown on the left.
Change that, and it will work fine.

Comment: excuse me while i go shoot myself